# convert a string to array of arrays

Tags: javascript

I have a string as a prototype of an array if arrays:

```
'[ [7,8,9], [12,13,14] ]'
```

Are there any solutions to convert this to array of arrays?

I have used `Array.from()` with no luck.

Comment: Use `JSON.parse()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`eval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) (usually not recommended):

```js
let str = '[ [7,8,9], [12,13,14] ]';
let arr = eval(str);
console.log(arr);
```

Or [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse):

```js
let str = '[ [7,8,9], [12,13,14] ]';
let arr = JSON.parse(str);
console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use `eval` but you know: `eval is evil` because it could be harmfull and should normally not be used.

```js
let str = '[ [7,8,9], [12,13,14] ]';

eval('arr='+str+';');
console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use JSON.parse()
Its parse string to JS object.